# How could the sorority sisters not catch Bluto?

Tags: plot-explanation, animal-house

In National Lampoon's Animal House, when Bluto uses a ladder to peep on a sorority, his face is right in front of the window, yet the women give no visible reaction, as if either they don't see him or (which seems even less likely) choose to ignore someone spying on them undress- how could he not get caught?

Answer (score 1):

Ever try looking out of a window from inside of a lighted room when it's dark outside? You can't see anything, because the reflections from inside are far brighter than what's outside.